# If $X$ is distributed normally with mean $0$, is it correct to say $X$ and $-X$ "have the same distribution"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology

> *Q*: If $X$ is distributed [normally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $0$, is it correct to say $X$ and $-X$ *have the same distribution*?

In a way, this seems correct: both $X$ and $-X$ have the same probability density functions.  But, in other ways, it seems incorrect: (a) they're clearly not independent, and (b) $X \neq -X$, in general.

Is there a better way of phrasing this, both in this case, and in general (where $X$ and $f(X)$ have the same probability density functions)?  Or is the original phrasing acceptable?

Comment: The third moment could be different.

Comment: Yes it is correct. Certainly $X$ is not the same as $-X$, and certainly they are not independent. But that does not affect the fact they have the same distribution. A more technical way of saying it is that they are identically distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Two random  variables $X,Y$ are equal in distribution if
$$
\mathbb{P}(X\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq z) \, \mbox{for all } z.
$$

It doesn't have to do with independance either. Clearly $X$ and $X$ have the same distribution but$\ldots$

Comment: So going off this we have $F_{-X}(x)=P(-X\leq x)=P(X\geq-x)$ but since $X$ is Normal distribution with mean 0 it is symmetric around 0 thus $P(X\geq-x)=P(X\leq x)=F_{X}(x)$ thus $X$ and $-X$ have same distribution

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ has a *normal* distribution, which is symmetric around its mean, then yes, $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution.

For example, if $X \sim N(0,17)$, then $-X \sim N(0,17)$.

In addition, $X$ and $-X$ are negatively correlated, since $-X = -x$ when $X = x$.
But two identically distributed variables *can* still be correlated, so that's OK.